# How can I find if a modem supports VDSL?

Tags: adsl2+, vdsl

This is my modem https://www.cnet.com/products/tp-link-td-w8901g-wireless-router-dsl-802-11b-g-desktop/ and I am interested to know how can I find that if it supports VDSL or not?

Comment: You should contact your DSL provider to determine if you are being provided ADSL or VDSL.  You should also read the specifications for the TP-LINK TD-W8901G from TP-LINK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google the model number shown in the article (`TD-W8901G`); visit the manufacturer's [product webpage](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/td-w8901g/v6/); download and skim through the [datasheet](https://static.tp-link.com/resources/document/datasheet/TD-W8901G_ds.zip).

- Usually the best/highest mode is mentioned in all the marketing material. But the TD-W8901G's description says "ADSL2+ modem" – if it supported VDSL, they would have advertised that fact.
- The second page, "Specifications", has a complete list of the ADSL modes (all the G.992.x standards) that the modem supports. But the VDSL standards (G.993.1, G.993.2) are not in the list, and there is no separate list for "VDSL modes" either.

From that you can make the conclusion that it does not support VDSL.